# Can I add user defined tag or name to a shape in xaml?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, shapes

I am trying to create different shapes using path element in xaml in C#. The goal is, I need to detect these shapes using another code and display different messages on the screen respectively. For instance, if I have two different path shapes:

**Shape1:**

```
<Path Data="F1 M 0.5,64.5001L 128.5,64.5001L 128.5,192.5L 
0.5,192.5L 0.500031,64.5L 64.5,0.499992L 192.5,0.500053L 
128.5,64.5L 192.5,0.499992L 192.5,128.5L 128.5,192.5" 
Fill="Transparent" Margin="352,216,352,227" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black"/>
```

**Shape2:**

```
<Path Data="F1 M 448,288L 448,128L 192,128L 192,288L 448,288 
M 416,256L 416,160L 224,160L 224,256L 416,256"
Fill="Transparent" Margin="352,216,352,227" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" />
```

My code displays and saves these shapes in a "xml" file. Now I want to determine if a given shape is **Shape1** or **Shape2** by reading through this saved xml file. So for that, I want to add some kind of tag like "Shape1" or "Shape2" for them. Is this possible and how? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create them as resources:

```
<Resources>
    <Path x:Key="OftenUsedShape_1" Data="F1 M 0.5,64.5001L 128.5,64.5001L 128.5,192.5L 
0.5,192.5L 0.500031,64.5L 64.5,0.499992L 192.5,0.500053L 
128.5,64.5L 192.5,0.499992L 192.5,128.5L 128.5,192.5" 
Fill="Transparent" Margin="352,216,352,227" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black"/>
</Resources>
```

And then use them as static resources

```
<PathUsingContainer>
   <StaticResource x:Key="OftenUsedShape_1"/>
</PathUsingContainer>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Tag%29;k%28VS.XamlEditor%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework) property.

If you want to be able to address them in code behind you can name them using the [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Name%29;k%28VS.XamlEditor%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework) property

Answer (score 1):

You can add a name using this

```
<Path x:Name="myShape" />
```

Answer (score 1):

`Tag` attribute is created to store any custom information. But if you only want to have an identifier you can very well use `Name` property. So eiter:

```
<Path Tag="Shape1" ... />
```

or:

```
<Path Name="Shape1" ... />
```